# Terminology of Address Types

Tags: smart-contracts, account, address, secret-key

What is the terminologi for an address that starts with `tz` and for one that starts with `KT1`? The former is controlled by a secret key, and the latter is controlled by a piece of Michelson code that was published on the blockchain.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between implicit vs originated accounts?](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/418/what-is-the-difference-between-implicit-vs-originated-accounts)

Comment: Not fully as the accepted answer uses "originated contracts" and the other uses "originated accounts".

Comment: @arvidj: this is a bit old. Since Babylon all accounts are delegatable, each smart contract has a script, and the only way to spend from or change the delegation of a smart contract is by running its code and having it emit the appropriate operation.

Comment: I was looking for the official terminology, so I could ensure we used the same words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in the [glossary](https://tezos.gitlab.io/user/glossary.html#account), `tz` accounts are called "implicit accounts" and `KT1` accounts are called "originated accounts" or "smart contracts" (these two expressions are synonyms since Babylon).

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the official documentation!